Optimize use of SafeFileHandle object
I am working on a graphics system that uses the console. The console is much larger than the default size (634 columns and 339 rows), so optimal output time is critical. I've looked through several questions on StackOverflow regarding fast output to the console, and have made a great deal of headway. However, I ran into a snag regarding the usage of a SafeFileHandle object.
The method that I'm calling to output to the console window is WriteConsoleOutputW(), which takes a SafeFileHandle as one of its arguments. This works fine, but I've noticed a drop in speed due to one critical detail.
A (severely) simplified version of the code I'm currently using to output to the console:
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
List<long> durations = new List<long>();

SafeFileHandle consoleHandle = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

for(int loop = 0; loop < 1000; loop++)
{
   CharInfo[] buf = new CharInfo[Console.WindowWidth * Console.WindowHeight]
   SmallRect rect = new SmallRect() { Left = 0, Top = 0, Right = (short)Console.WindowWidth, Bottom = (short)Console.WindowHeight };

   for(int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
   {
      buf[i].Char.AsciiChar = 67;
      buf[i].Attributes = 15;
   }

   timer.Restart();

   WriteConsoleOutputW(consoleHandle, buf, new Coord() { X = (short)Console.WindowWidth, Y = (short)Console.WindowHeight }, new Coord() { X = 0, Y = 0 }, ref rect);

   timer.Stop();
   durations.Add(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

Console.WriteLine("Average Milliseconds: " + durations.Average());

This renders images on the console fairly quickly. The following block of code, albeit making the process slower overall, ended up making the output time of WriteConsoleOutputW() faster:
Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
List<long> durations = new List<long>();

for(int loop = 0; loop < 1000; loop++)
{
   SafeFileHandle consoleHandle = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
   CharInfo[] buf = new CharInfo[Console.WindowWidth * Console.WindowHeight]
   SmallRect rect = new SmallRect() { Left = 0, Top = 0, Right = (short)Console.WindowWidth, Bottom = (short)Console.WindowHeight };

   for(int i = 0; i < buf.Length; i++)
   {
      buf[i].Char.AsciiChar = 67;
      buf[i].Attributes = 15;
   }

   timer.Restart();

   WriteConsoleOutputW(consoleHandle, buf, new Coord() { X = (short)Console.WindowWidth, Y = (short)Console.WindowHeight }, new Coord() { X = 0, Y = 0 }, ref rect);

   timer.Stop();
   durations.Add(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

Console.WriteLine("Average Milliseconds: " + durations.Average());

The act of initializing consoleHandle within the same scope as the call to WriteConsoleOutputW() ended up making WriteConsoleOutputW() run around 5ms faster on average. I know that there is some optimization that is done by the compiler when a variable is only used within the exact scope it was created. However, the call to CreateFile() to create consoleHandle on each iteration was slow enough to make the overall speed of each iteration worse than in the previous block of code.
My question is this: Is there any way to gain the optimization of the second block of code without the slowdown of CreateFile() every iteration? Is there a faster way to create the object than CreateFile(), or is there some way to make the compiler still use the optimized process while also keeping the initialization of consoleHandle outside of the scope of the call to WriteConsoleOutputW(), like in the first block of code? I realize I may be trying to have my cake and eat it too, but if there is a way to get that 5ms speed-up, I'd really appreciate any input someone might have on this issue.
I have tried using SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle() to create a duplicate SafeFileHandle object within the scope of the call to WriteConsoleOutputW(), but that would fail after a few iterations, since the handle became outdated. I tried creating a FileStream object within each iteration instead of SafeFileHandle, but that was also too slow.

I don't understand what you're saying.  "The act of initializing consoleHandle" is done by calling "CreateFile".  Right?  Those are two phrases that mean the exact same thing.  You can't initialize consoleHandle unless you call CreateFile, and of course it's foolish to create the file over and over and over.

How are you profiling the execution time? "5ms faster" than what? Is the improvement consistent across 100 iteration? 1 million?

@TimRoberts Yes, initializing consoleHandle is done by calling CreateFile. I was asking if there was some other faster way to create a SafeFileHandle object that was associated with the console window that I was unaware of, whether that meant another method other than CreateFile that returns a SafeFileHandle object, or some other way of cloning consoleHandle within the scope of the call to WriteConsoleOutputW. (SafeFileHandle does not use ICloneable interface, so I couldn't use consoleHandle.Clone() either)

Are you sure this is the route you want to go down when the documentation for this method recommends not using it for new development?

@MathiasR.Jessen The second block of code resulted in making WriteConsoleOutputW run 5ms faster on average compared to the first block of code. This improvement has been consistent for 1000 iterations when outputting a total of 214926 characters (634 x 339) to the console each time.

@Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not necessarily committed to this route. It's just the fastest output to the console that I've found so far. I'm definitely open to other ways of doing equally fast output to the console. I'm not open to creating my own console, though, since that would defeat the purpose of the project. I wanted to see how far I could push the standard Windows console in terms of rendering graphics.

But how are you measuring it?

Isn't the second one faster because it writes console buffer from scratch every time?

SafeFileHandle is just an integer.  There cannot be any significant time associated with its instantiation.

@MathiasR.Jessen I'm measuring it using a Stopwatch object. I tried using BenchmarkDotNet, but since you can only benchmark an entire method rather than one part of the method (in this case, just the call to WriteConsoleOutputW), I couldn't get it to work.

@shingo No, the second one is not faster. Both the first and second block of code write the console buffer from scratch every time in the exact same way. The only difference between the two blocks of code is that the first one initializes consoleHandle once outside of the while-loop, whereas the second block initializes consoleHandle every iteration within the while-loop.

@TimRoberts I do not believe SafeFileHandle is just an integer. Looking at the documentation for the object (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle?view=net-8.0), it does only have one field, which is an IntPtr, but it has other properties and methods as well. I timed how long it took for CreateFile to run, and it averaged out to around 10ms on my machine.

@SilverSensei that makes perfect sense, can you include that in the sample code in your question? You're specifically asking about unexpected discrepancies in measurements you're making, so including the code that makes those measurements will make it much easier to attempt to reproduce the issue :)

@MathiasR.Jessen Fair point. I've edited the post to more accurately show how I was testing the code. Thanks for recommending that I add that!

I do not believe CreateFile takes 10ms on any machine.  Exactly how are you measuring that?  Also remember that methods in an object do not cost anything to set up.

I tried the 2 methods for several times, the average time of both I got are mostly around 0.13ms (much less than 5ms, except for the first few runs), at least it cannot be clearly seen that the latter has a shorter executing time. BTW I am on Win10.

@TimRoberts I am using a Stopwatch object, calling Restart() immediately before calling CreateFile, and calling Stop() immediately after CreateFile. When I compile this in Debug mode, it averages around 10ms, and in Release, around 8.5ms. It may have to do with the fact that I'm making the console larger than normal (634 columns and 339 rows), but that is consistently the time I get when calling CreateFile. That is true, methods don't take any time to setup. My bad.

@shingo Part of why my time would be so much longer than yours is that I've made the console much larger than normal (634 columns and 339 rows). If you were running this code with the normal-sized console, it would be insanely fast, like your attempts showed. I will update the main post to point out that I'm working with a much larger console. And the 5ms difference is only in regard to comparing the runtime of WriteConsoleOutputW between the two blocks of code, not the runtime of the entire block of code.

None of this makes much sense.  High odds you're profiling the security software installed on the machine.  Consoles are owned by another process (conhost.exe), the required underlying process interop is always suspect.

@HansPassant I'm not sure I fully grasp what you've written. Do you have any ideas as to how to further speed-up the runtime of WriteConsoleOutputW based on what you know about how consoles are handled, or ideas on how to speed-up console output in general?
